# summary = 0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg: 0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err: 0 (0.00%)" in JMeter

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have installed JMeter in my new system. Create a script and trying to execute from non-GUI mode. But the script is not getting executed and it gives below summary result.

```
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s 
Avg:     0 
Min: 9223372036854775807 
Max: -9223372036854775808 
Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

What could be the reason? How to resolve this? Kindly guide me as I am from the Loadrunner background.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the script hasn't generated any results as it failed to execute any [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers).

You can always look into [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file - most probably it will contain sufficient information to get to the bottom of the issue, if not - you will be able to increase JMeter log verbosity for the components you're using or the whole JMeter engine.

The most common reasons are:

- Missing file referenced in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [Missing JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
- The [script version](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) is not compatible with the JMeter version

So look into *jmeter.log* file and if you won't be able to figure out what's wrong - post its contents here

Comment: I have updated all the plugin. The JMeter script is also compatible with my JMeter. Also there is not CSV Data set config element I used in my script. Then also it is not working. Below is the jmeter.log file. Let me know if I am doing something wrong.